# Porting Lean 3 to Lean 4 Process (and the state of general integration in Lean 4)

Tags: lean, lean4, lean3, lean-mathlib

I found this [reference](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lt2021/slides/floris-measure.pdf) for measure-theoretic integration in Lean. However, I cannot find any integration in the Lean 4 Measure Theory library. Have these not yet been ported, or can they be found elsewhere? Would it be particularly difficult to do this? I'd like to be able to talk about general integration in the setting of a functional analysis project I've been considering, but I unfortunately don't know anything about porting from Lean 3 to Lean 4.

Hence the second part of the question: How does porting form Lean 3 to Lean 4 work? What process goes into adapting the library? Is it all manual work, or do we have a program capable to converting between the two?

Comment: Porting is nearly done, we're looking at early to mid July for the completion. You can check which mathlib3 files have been ported here https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib-port-status/

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Impressive. Is it possible that these definitions are 3rd party work that hasn't been added to the library? I don't see any measure theory files in progress.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Btw, who does the porting? Is it just individuals working for Microsoft?

Comment: @AlexByard The porting (as with mathlib) is open source and done by a team of people, many in academics, like Kevin Buzzard.  As for how it works you can find the documentation on the porting wiki: https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib4/wiki/Porting-wiki

Comment: @AlexByard The “interval integral” seems to be ported: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/MeasureTheory/Integral/IntervalIntegral.html

Comment: @JasonRute Just ran `lake update` and a whole bunch of new files were added to MeasureTheory. Seems that these have been ported recently.

Comment: unfortunately it broke everything...

Comment: @AlexByard, if you come over to https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/ and post a message, we can help you work out what "it" and "everything" are, and how to make them not broken. :-)

Comment: @KimLiesinger I was able to revert back to a previous commit on my git project, but running lake update again breaks "everything". I'll come over and post a message about it, thanks : )

Comment: @KimLiesinger What stream should I post the message in, by the way?

Comment: the #new-members stream